# Akka Streams + Akka Http Pass parameter through the flow

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have the following code snippet:

```
    case class SomeClass(param1:String,param2:String,param3:String)

    val someClassActorSource: Source[SomeClass, ActorRef] = Source
      .actorPublisher[SomeClass](Props[SomeClassActorPublisher])

    val someFlow: ActorRef = Flow[SomeClass]

        .mapAsync(3)(f=> getDocumentById(f))

        .map(f =>{
          val request = HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.POST, uri = "http://localhost:8000/test")
            .withEntity(ContentTypes.`text/xml(UTF-8)`, ByteString(f.a)
            )
          (request,request)

        }).via(connection)

        //Parsing Response
        .mapAsync(3){
          case (Success(HttpResponse(status, _, entity, _)),request)=>
            entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _)
        }
        .map(resp =>parse(resp.utf8String,?????????????) )
        .to(Sink.someSink{....})
        .runWith(someClassActorSource)

    def parse(resp:String,parseParam:String)=????
```

and somewhere in the code I'm sending message to Flow:

```
someflow ! SomeClass("a","b","c")
someflow ! SomeClass("a1","b1","c1")
```

My problem is that method parse should use param2 from original case class

So for first message it should be

```
  parse(response,"b")
```

and for second message it should be

```
  parse(response,"b1")
```

So the question is, how can I fetch a parameter from the method I submitted to the flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `connection` value is being instantiated via

```
val connection = Http().cachedHostConnectionPool(...)
```

You can use the fact that the Connection takes in a tuple and instead of simply passing the `request` twice in the tuple you can pass in the inputted `SomeClass`.  This `SomeClass` instance will have to go through each of your `Flow` values to make it to the parsing stage.

Modifying your code a bit:

```
val getDocumentFlow = 
  Flow[SomeClass].mapAsync(3)(f => getSomDocumentById(f).map( d => d -> f))
```

Your question doesn't state the return type from `getDocumentById` so I'm just using `Document`:

```
val documentToRequest = 
  Flow[(Document, SomeClass)] map { case (document, someClass) =>
    val request = ...

    (request, someClass)
  }

val parseResponse = 
  Flow[(Try[HttpResponse], SomeClass)].mapAsync(3){
    case (Success(HttpResponse(status, _, entity, _)), someClass) =>
      entity
        .dataBytes
        .runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _)
        .map(e => e -> someClass)
  }

val parseEntity = Flow[(ByteString, SomeClass)] map { 
  case (entity, someClass) => parse(entity.utf8String, someClass)
}
```

These flows can then be used as described in the question:

```
val someFlow = 
  someClassActorSource
    .via(getDocumentFlow)
    .via(documentToRequest)
    .via(connection)
    .via(parseResponse)
    .via(parseEntity)
    .to(Sink.someSink{...})
    .run()
```